# Update List Item using Visual Studio 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, visual-studio-2013

I am busy developing a Leave application using Visual Studio 2013 with a two stage approval workflow.

I want the workflow to update a list(not the list on which the workflow runs) after the second approval stage has been approved.

It must lookup the field that contains the current logged in user name and then update only the column for which he requested leave. eg annual,sick,study etc. it can always only be one.

I have the following in the workflow :

1 . To get the Id of the item to update : LookupSPListItemId with this properties
[image: LookupSPListItemId Properties]

2. Build the search string to look for the column : BuildCollection with this properties [image: BuildCollection<String> Properties 1]

collection is >In > String > leaveType
(I cant post more images)

3. Then I use LookupSPListItem to find the item to update
4. Then I update that item with the the number obtained in 3 minus the number of days requested.

The problem I have is the JSON request that is formulated is wrong . It looks like this http:///_api/web/lists/(guid'list GUID')/items(1)$**select=IDLeaveType**

It keeps on putting the word ID in front of my leave type selector!

Any Ideas would be appreciated